# How to manage a pool of processes?

Tags: python, windows, events, multiprocessing, pool

I'm trying to set up a multiprocessing pool on Windows 10.

Basically some cpus (12 in my case) should read from a `Qin`and write results to `Qout`. When writing `'end'` in `Qin` the process should stop.

For some reason the process hangs.

I developed a simple version:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool, Queue, Event
import os,time


def worker( Qin, Qout, event):
    time.sleep(5)
    while True:
        item = Qin.get()
        if item == 'end':
            event.set()
        else:
            Qout.put(item)
        time.sleep(1)

def manager():
    Qin,Qout,event= Queue(), Queue(), Event()
    processes = os.cpu_count()
    pool = Pool(processes=processes)
    for _ in range(processes):
        pool.apply_async(worker,args= (Qin,Qout,event,))
    for i in range(100):
        print(i)
        Qin.put(i)

    Qin.put('end')

    pool.close()
    event.wait()
    pool.terminate()
    return Qout

Qout = manager()
```

Comment: If you're on windows you need a check for `__main__`, otherwise each process will call `manager` again, and again, and again... See **Safe importing of main module** in the [spawn and forkserver start methods](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html?highlight=process#the-spawn-and-forkserver-start-methods) documentation

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand how correctly asynchronous programming works in python. When you call apply_async you get Future object. The Queue implementation in python relies on a system pipe to transmit the data from one process to another and some semaphores to protect the read and write on this pipe.

```
from multiprocessing import Pool, Queue, Event
import os
import time
import multiprocessing

def worker( Qin, Qout, event):
    print('worker')
    time.sleep(1)
    event.set()

def manager():
    processes = multiprocessing.cpu_count()
    m = multiprocessing.Manager()
    Qin = m.Queue()
    Qout = m.Queue()
    event = m.Event()
    pool = Pool(processes=processes)
    result = pool.apply_async(worker, (Qin, Qout, event))
    result.get()
    pool.close()
    event.wait()
    return Qout

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Qout = manager()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason your code hangs is because all the worker tasks end up waiting for something to appear on the input queue with the `item = Qin.get()` line at the same time because `get()` "blocks" waiting for something to be placed in the queue. One way to avoid that is to use the non-blocking `get_nowait()` method instead. Doing so requires code to handle any `Empty` exception it may raise, but it avoids having any further execution in that process effectively halted at that point.

Also for things to work, you need to create and use a `multiprocessing.Manager` which creates a server process which holds Python objects and allows other processes to manipulate them via proxies. See the "Server process" part of the [**Sharing state between processes**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#sharing-state-between-processes) section of the documentation.

Also, when using `multiprocessing` on Windows, it's very important to make sure the main process' code is executed conditionally by putting it inside an `if __name__ == '__main__':` statement. This is because of how the module has been  implemented on that platform—otherwise that code will be executed again each time another concurrent task is started (which involves it being `import`ed by them).

Below is your code with the modification needed so it uses a `multiprocessing.Manager`. Note I changed the name of your `manager()` function to avoid confusion with the `multiprocessing.Manager` which it uses to create the shared objects.

```
import multiprocessing
from queue import Empty as QueueEmpty
import os
import time

END_MARKER = 'end'


def worker(id, Qin, Qout, event):
    while True:
        try:
            item = Qin.get_nowait()  # Non-blocking.
        except QueueEmpty:
            if event.is_set():  # Last item seen?
               break
            continue # Keep polling.

        if item == END_MARKER:  # Last item?
            event.set()
            break  # Quit.

        Qout.put('{} via worker {}'.format(item, id))
        time.sleep(.25)


def pool_manager():
    processes = os.cpu_count()
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=processes)
    manager = multiprocessing.Manager()
    Qin, Qout, event = manager.Queue(), manager.Queue(), manager.Event()

    for i in range(100):
        Qin.put(i)

    Qin.put(END_MARKER)

    for id in range(processes):
        pool.apply_async(worker, (id, Qin, Qout, event))

    pool.close()  # Done adding tasks.
    pool.join()  # Wait for all tasks to complete.

    return Qout


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('Processing')
    Qout = pool_manager()

    print('Contents of Qout:')
    while not Qout.empty():
        item = Qout.get()
        print(' ', item)

    print('End of script')
```